# Configure an External LDAP User Store with WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: openldap, wso2

My Current configuration is

#

```
 <UserManager>
    <Realm>
        <Configuration>
                <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole> 
                <AdminUser>
                     <UserName>admin</UserName>
                     <Password>XXXXXX</Password>
                </AdminUser>
            <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName> <!-- By default users in     thsi role sees the registry root -->
<!--            <ReadOnly>false</ReadOnly> -->
            <MaxUserNameListLength>500</MaxUserNameListLength>
            <Property name="url">jdbc:h2:repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB</Property>
            <Property name="userName">wso2carbon</Property>
            <Property name="password">wso2carbon</Property>
            <Property name="driverName">org.h2.Driver</Property>
            <Property name="maxActive">50</Property>
            <Property name="maxWait">60000</Property>
            <Property name="minIdle">5</Property>
        </Configuration>
        <UserStoreManager
            class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPUserStoreManager">
            <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://localhost:389</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionName">cn=admin,dc=ysd,dc=com</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionPassword">admin32</Property>
            <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=People,dc=ysd,dc=com</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
            <Property name="ReadLDAPGroups">false</Property>
            <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=People,dc=ysd,dc=com</Property>
            <Property name="GroupSearchFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
            <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
        </UserStoreManager>
        <AuthorizationManager
            class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager">
        </AuthorizationManager>
    </Realm>
</UserManager>`
```

#

**Iam geeting following error while starting server.**
**ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm} -  Cannot create org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPUserStoreManager . Error is : null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**
..............
............
............

**Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: LDAPUserStoreManager is unable to operate in Read-Write mode. This is invalid configuration. It can only operate in ReadOnly mode
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPUserStoreManager.(LDAPUserStoreManager.java:97)
        ... 25 more**

Comment: I have similar problems, but someone moved my posts to serverfault so that I didn't have any support from the Wso2 guys there...

Answer (score 1):

What is your exact requirement ? Do you want the Identity Server to do Read-Write operation on the external LDAP or do you want to do only the Read operations ?

You get this exception because you are trying to use the read only ldap user store for both read-write operations. Set the parameter `<ReadOnly>false</ReadOnly>`to true, then this error would go away.

But if your requirement is to use IS for both read write operations use the ApacheDSUserStoreManager. You can use the LDAPUserStoreManager for that.